# Extracting common sequences from time sequence data

Tags: time-series, spatial, unsupervised-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a large number of time ordered location traces that I'd like to extract common sequences from.  These locations are mapped from latitude, longitude pairs to a 2D aggregation bucket to handle noise and sampling differences.

For example, if a person makes a trip that looks like mnABCDefg (lower case letters for illustrative purposes to make the pattern more obvious) and another person makes the trip ghiklmnABCDrtu, and other makes a trip like ABCDxyz, I'd like to be able to be able to extract ABCD in an unsupervised manner from this data.

Naturally, this being real world data, for longer sequences, we might often have missing or noisy steps (eg. if the common pattern is ABCDEFGHIJK we'd want ABCDEFFHIJK and ABCDEFHIJK to ideally still accrue to the pattern within some amount of error).

Is this a well known problem with solutions?  Googling around does not seem to bring anything up.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean time series (real valued) or time sequences (discrete, categorical).

If the former, the Matrix Profile is all you need.

http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/MatrixProfile.html

Comment: Sadly it is time sequences over the latitude, longitude aggregated by square buckets.